# Leak when autoreleased in return

Tags: xcode, pointers, return, memory-leaks, autorelease

I found this strange thing. XCode instruments tell me that this line

```
return (SDZPerson*)[[[SDZPerson alloc] initWithNode: node] autorelease];
```

leaks. But if i change it to:

```
SDZPerson* person = [[[SDZPerson alloc] initWithNode: node] autorelease];
return person;
```

Instruments no longer report leak in this place. Is it really a leak or is it nothing?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that's actually where the leak occurs? Usually it just says that's where the object was *allocated*.

Comment: As i said, when i change it to two lines, the warning disappears. There are no more leaks in app, just this one line.

Comment: Why do you add typecasting to `SDZPerson *` in first snippet?

Comment: I fixed the init method in second snippet. They both init identically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the two code snippets are slightly different (the 1st one contain a typecasting), I doubt the instruments indicate this as a leak due to the autorelease in the return statement.

Adding autorelease in the return statement can be used.

You should give it a try to

```
SDZPerson* person = [[SDZPerson alloc] init];
/** do your stuff here if needed */
return [person autorelease];
```

or even

```
return [[[SDZPerson alloc] init] autorelease;
```

Comment: Thank you. At least i know this is not a mistake. Maybe there is some other leak, or there is just instruments misunderstanding. Thank you for your quick answer.